# Invoke ifconfig inside a script which opens multiple PowerShell's windows

Tags: powershell

Goal: executing commands (ifconfig, pwd etc.), which usually are written in PowerShell console, in a script that calls multiple PowerShell's windows.

E.g. I'd like to invoke the command ifconfig inside multiple PowerShell's windows by using a script; to do that I tried to write the following code:

```
$i=1
for(; $i -le 2; $i++)
{
    Start-Process powershell.exe
    Invoke-Expression -Command "ipconfig"
}
```

When I executed the above code in PowerShell ISE, the result is two powershell's windows, but inside them there isn't the output of the command ifconfig.

Comment: I recommend figuring out first how to get one window open with the command(s) you’d like before trying to do multiple.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @DougMaurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not running any commands at all in the new shells, you're just starting them and then independently doing "ipconfig" in your current session. To do what you want you need to pass the commands as arguments to the new PowerShell processes.

```
$i=1
for(; $i -le 2; $i++)
{
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoExit','-Command ipconfig'
}
```

The `-NoExit` part is necessary if you want the PowerShell windows to stay open, without it they'll close after running ipconfig.